# SAS DO LOOP OUTPUT

Tags: sas, do-loops

I am trying to understand this SAS question and how the output statement works here. The question asks what the values of i and x are.

But when I add an output statement it shows 3 observations x 1,3,5 and i 1,3,5.

(I had thought of the output statement as writing the current values, but I'm not sure what that means here)

This is the code and explanation it gives,

```
data new;
x = 0;
do i = 1 to 5 by 2;
x = i;
end;
run;

Answer

x=5 i=7

Step check

1. x=0, i=1
2. x=1, i=3
3. x=3  i=5
4  x=5  i=7
```

Comment: Where did you add the OUTPUT statement?

Comment: I only put one output after x = i

Comment: What is STEP CHECK supposed to be?  Is that supposed to show values of those variables? At what point in the data step is it being checked?

Comment: I'm not sure, the exam question showed that as part of the answer

Comment: step check is the check of the values at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is correct. The DO loop terminates when the value is 7. 
So in the last iteration of the loop, i=5, then it increments in the DO statement, realizes it's past the interval for the loop and then terminates. X remains 5 because the loop was never entered, but i is 7.

If you add OUTPUT statements, note the plurality, then you can see it. 
Note I used PUT in the log to make the output easier to read.

```
data new;
    x=0;

    do i=1 to 5 by 2;
        x=i;
        output;
    end;
    output;
run;
```

Output:

```
 69         data new;
 70         file log dsd;
 71         x = 0;
 72         do i = 1 to 5 by 2;
 73         x = i;
 74         put _all_;
 75         end;
 76         put _all_;
 77         run;

 x=1 i=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
 x=3 i=3 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
 x=5 i=5 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
 x=5 i=7 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! That's how I had pictured it looping, so does that mean the step check they give is wong? That threw me off

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the bottom part of that question is trying show/ask.  But if you add some PUT statements and run the code you can see how the values change.

```
2511  data new;
2512  putlog 'Loc 1 ' x= i=;
2513  x = 0;
2514  putlog 'Loc 2 ' x= i=;
2515  do i = 1 to 5 by 2;
2516  putlog 'Loc 3 ' x= i=;
2517  x = i;
2518  putlog 'Loc 4 ' x= i=;
2519  end;
2520  putlog 'Loc 5 ' x= i=;
2521  run;

Loc 1 x=. i=.
Loc 2 x=0 i=.
Loc 3 x=0 i=1
Loc 4 x=1 i=1
Loc 3 x=1 i=3
Loc 4 x=3 i=3
Loc 3 x=3 i=5
Loc 4 x=5 i=5
Loc 5 x=5 i=7
NOTE: The data set WORK.NEW has 1 observations and 2 variables.
```

Comment: Thank you. Why does this way vary from using "put _all_" in the log, this  way shows extra steps? And the log count goes 1,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,5

Comment: The values of X and I will be displayed the same whether you use `x= i=` or `_all_` you just don't clutter the log with those other variables you don't need. The `Loc n` values are constant text in each different `put` statement so you can see in the log which statement it was that wrote that line and trace how the program is flowing.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks. I'm just trying to understand the difference between these values and the values at the bottom of Reeza's explanation?